# Speed up Animation anime.js

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I am trying to implement the animation in this website(

```
var timeline = anime.timeline({ autoplay: true, direction: 'alternate', loop: true });

https://codepen.io/ainalem/pen/VWJRav?editors=1100
```

) in my angular7 app. Everything was fine, but the animation is playing too slow. Is it because of my local server? I already have the  I didn't change any line of code. 
Anyone knows how to fix this. Here is my git repo.
https://github.com/ArtzGroup/Artix.git

Comment: lower the `duration` : `duration: 50`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't help. It animates slowly. If I give the duration: 0, it doesn't animate at all. If I give duration: 1 it's same as 1000. Actaully I have used, particleJs and a animejs already in that page, and I have added this as a component.

Comment: https://codepen.io/takius/pen/vYBMywQ?editors=0010

Comment: Exactly what part is slow?

Comment: Hi @coolpasta, here is my git repo. I added it as a component. Can you please help me fix this. Thanks. https://github.com/ArtzGroup/Artix.git